# GCC fails to include header with -l option specified

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

This is the image with the code, directories and the terminal error-output:
[image: This is the image with the code, directories and the terminal error-output]

I already tried to specify the include path from the root but that failed too. Am I just overlooking something for hours and being dumb or what is it?

Comment: .cpp is a very uncommon suffix for C source files.

Comment: Code has to be posted **as text** and in the question itself. Not as image or link.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to `-I` include (an uppercase i like in include) your headers. Not `-l` (lowercase L).

Comment: Excuse me if i'm wrong, but the l/L is lowercase. If you meant uppercase L, I also tried it.

Comment: In the image you've shown, you are using the option -l (lowercase L as in lamp).  That is the option you use to tell the compiler where to find libraries, not header files.  The option you should be using to tell the compiler where to find header files is -I (capital I as in include).

Comment: No. Not a L. Use an I (uppercase i). You want to include header files. Not a lib.

Comment: I've edit my answer to be more clear.